# How to set especific method title description in a javadoc block?

Tags: java, javadoc

I start writing the javadoc for a method like this:

```
/**
     * This is my method's title
     * I DON'T want this line to be shown as title in the resumed method espec
     * Any lines after this are not shown. though ..
     *<pre>
     *
     * {@code
     *  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     *      Object object = arr[i];
        }
     * }
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * @param event Evento que por defecto se recibe en un Nodo, en este caso corresponde al click sobre <code>{@link #button1}</code>
     */
    @FXML private void modificarLabel(ActionEvent event) {
```

In the generated index.html shows this:

> modificarLabel(javafx.event.ActionEvent event)
>   Método para modificar el valor de un Label I DON'T want this line to be shown as title in the resumed method espec

How to set a certain or maybe first line to be shown as the *title description* for the method? Also, how can I discard showing the whole package hierarchy for classes?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want the first line to be the 'brief' title, then you need to finish that line with a full stop / period "**.**".

I've observed that Javadoc and Doxygen differ in this.  Doxygen finishes the title at either the first "**.**" *or* a new line.  Javadoc needs the "**.**"